# Question about path integral over unit circle

Tags: definite-integrals, vector-analysis, line-integrals

We just learned about path integrals today, and have this on our online homework:

Let $\mathbf{y}(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ be the path defining the outside of the unit circle. Let $\mathbf{F}$ be the vector field $\mathbf{F}(x,y)=(x+e^{x^2}, -2xye^{x^2})$. Calculate the path integral of $\mathbf{F}$ along the path.

I've done path integrals before, and my first thought based on this chapter is that I need the norm of $\mathbf{F}$.

$$T_x=(2x^2e^{x^2}, -2x^2ye^{x^2})$$
$$T_y=(0, -2xe^{x^2})$$

The norm is their cross product divided by length of the cross product:
$$T_x \times T_y = (0, 0, -4x^3e^{2x^2})$$
$$||T_x \times T_y||=\sqrt{(-4x^3e^{2x^2})^2}=4x^3e^{2x^2}$$
$$\mathbf{n}=\frac{(0, 0, -4x^3e^{2x^2})}{4x^3e^{2x^2}}=(0,0,-1)$$

Now is when I get confused. What exactly is the path, and where does $\mathbf{y}(t)$ come into play?

Comment: You are either looking at a wrong section in your notes or confusing the vector field with the path of integration (or both). In particular, why do you think you need the norm of the vector field $\mathbf{F}$?

Comment: @zipirovich our hint is to look at Theorem 4, which is the theorem of the norm. Am I taking the norm of the wrong thing, should I have taken the norm of y(t) instead?

Comment: Unless you tell me what this "Theorem 4" says, I can't comment on your attempt to apply it. But I do know that you are calculating wrong things. You shouldn't need the norm of $\mathbf{F}$. I'm not even sure that need any norms here...